# 2006 Pontiac Vibe Heating problems - Toyota engine

Tags: pontiac, heater, heater-blower, vibe

To start, I had my mechanic disconnect the compressor for my A/C about 6 months ago. He said my car would be fine without it.

Now, with that being said, my heat suddenly stopped working properly. When I turn my heat on the first two settings, there is no heat coming out of any of the vents. The only way I can get heat to come out is if I put it on full blast. My heat has always worked fine on all settings up until now.

I'm not sure if disconnecting my compressor has anything to do with this, but I figured I'd mention it just in case. I don't want to suddenly run out of heat in the middle of winter but I also can't drop my car off to my mechanic until the weekend because of school. Am I okay to drive it until then?

Comment: What first two settings? The blower speed control? Sounds like a bad blower motor resistor if it is.

Comment: @Jason D could be the door actuator or blend door that fell on top of the fan motor, preventing air flow

Answer (score 0):

This sounds unrelated to the compressor.  Your car should be fine to drive, as long as it is not overheating.  Your heat comes from the coolant system, so issues with heat can be linked with overheating.

When you say 'stopped working,' do you mean the the fan stopped spinning, or it is only blowing cold air?  If the fan stopped spinning, I agree with @Ben.  If it is only blowing cold air, I believe your heater core is clogged, or the diverter valve is having issues.  The fix would be to flush the coolant system and replace the diverter valve if it is faulty.